# Video link not playing

Tags: css, html, video, html5-video

I am using lightbox from Sublime video player (http://www.sublimevideo.net/demos/lightbox/custom-overlay-opacity) to play a link to the video but it doesnt open the video

Here is the code for the video .How do i get the link to the vide working

```
<div id = "demo">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="sublime zoomable" href="#video1" data-settings="overlay-opacity:0.9"><h3>Watch Demo</h3>
</td>
  <td>
<img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="50" height="50" /> 
  <!-- <span class="zoom_icon"></span> -->

</td>
</tr> 
</a>


<video id="video1" data-settings="uid:demo-lightbox-custom-overlay-opacity; autoresize:fit;" title="Demo: Lightbox, Custom overlay opacity" poster="assets/images/logo.png" width="640" height="360" preload="none" style="display:none">
<source src="assets/DemoVideo.mp4"/>
<!-- <source src="assets/DemoVideo.mp4.webm"/> -->
</video>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code the video tag is set to hidden  `style="display:none"` all you have to do is to add a jQuery function that detect if the image was clicked or not. In your code I added a `toggle()` function so if you click the image the video tag will be displayed-->`show()` it you click one again it will be hidden--> `hide()`

Update : [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hx9jjsb/1/)

If you want to start the video once you click the image you can add inside the click function `document.getElementById('video1').play();` you can also stop the video once you hide the video tag by clicking you image for the second time `document.getElementById('video1').pause();`

[The fiddele](http://jsfiddle.net/1hx9jjsb/4/)

Comment: Hey Amani ,Thanks but it still doesnt play the video in the code http://jsfiddle.net/tr3j5u37

Comment: Is there a way the video can be launched on clicking the image instead of just the player being launched(and the video not being played).In their demos the video plays automatically on clicking the thumbnail image

Comment: yes you can do this with javascript, please mark the question as accepted if it answers your question

Comment: @user35434494 updated another time: I added a stop function to stop the video if it is hidden

Comment: Does the video play on your end it doesnt on y end.It just show the that play button has changed but the vide doesnt play

Comment: It does work I tested with Firefox and Chrome, this is the link-->    http://jsfiddle.net/1hx9jjsb/4/

Answer (score 0):

As far as the default video tag goes the source will the video codec example

```
<source src="assets/DemoVideo.mp4"/>
```

it will require type="video/mp4" so the full code will look below

```
<source src="assets/DemoVideo.mp4"type="video/mp4">
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: The video link still doesnt open the video

Comment: can you setup a fiddle

Comment: your missing the JS source http://jsfiddle.net/qhbvwev5/5/ it shows up at last step after you upload the video :)

Comment: ha! I am wondering what changes were mede tot he code to get it to show up?

Comment: i just added the external source for js on fiddle this is how it should look like http://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/YOURID.js

Comment: the reason is because the js link is given to you by sublimevideo after you upload the video it gives you the JS with your ID and then it gives you html & css code so you could add to your website